# Android retrofit headers content to be added

Tags: android, header, retrofit

I have a question about retrofit headers in Android.
Can i add any headers i want? whatever information? or I need to follow some rules, like RESTful API. Are there any mandatory information in a certain format need to be added in Headers?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add header. Please try this way it will help you

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
                interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    
                OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
                try {
                    httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                            Request original = chain.request();
                            Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                                    .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
                            Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                            return chain.proceed(request);
                        }
                    });
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                        readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                        writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
    
                String baseUrl = BASEURL;
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .client(okHttpClient)
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                webApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
```

Comment: Hi，Thanks for you answer. Actually i mean what information i need to add to in headers. In your example there is : "Connection","keep-alive".  is it mandatory? can I write "Connection Hallo Kitty","Roger Hallo Kitty" :) , whatever information i want to add?

Comment: You can add like access token, device type, app type,  etc.. which you want common for all Apis and what API side or backend side need in header.

Comment: many thanks!!! applause! so it is flexibel and depends on what API/Backend side needs.